# Symfony 5 :Relation ManyToMany do not save

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

in my project i create 2 entities :Projects & category.They are a ManyToMany relation [MySql shema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygPCJ.png)
im using Easy-admin bundle trying to Manage my database but the problem is when i try to add a category to a project it will not save, it work when i try to add a project to a category but i don't know why it fails in the other way  . thanks for help :)

Category

```
  <?php

   namespace App\Entity;

  use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

  /**
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
   * @ORM\Table(name="category")
   */
   class Category
   {
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
      */
 private $title;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="text")
   */
     private $body;

 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */
 private $image;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Projects::class, inversedBy="category",cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 */
private $projects;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->projects = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTitle(): ?string
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setTitle(string $title): self
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

public function getBody(): ?string
{
    return $this->body;
}

public function setBody(string $body): self
{
    $this->body = $body;

    return $this;
}

public function getImage(): ?string
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function setImage(string $image): self
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|projects[]
 */
public function getProjects(): Collection
{
    return $this->projects;
}

public function addProjects(projects  $project): self
{
    if (!$this->projects->contains($project)) {
        $this->projects[] = $project;
        $project->addCategory($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeProjects(projects $project): self
{
    if ($this->projects->contains($project)) {
        $this->projects->removeElement($project);
        $project->removeCategory($this);
    }

    return $this;
}


public function __toString()
{
   return $this->title;
}

}
```

projects

```
<?php

 namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProjectsRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProjectsRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="projects")
 */
 class Projects
 {
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $body;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $image;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, mappedBy="projects",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $category;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->category = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTitle(): ?string
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setTitle(string $title): self
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

public function getBody(): ?string
{
    return $this->body;
}

public function setBody(string $body): self
{
    $this->body = $body;

    return $this;
}

public function getImage(): ?string
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function setImage(string $image): self
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|category
 */
public function getCategory(): Collection
{
    return $this->category;
}

public function addCategory(category $category): self
{
    if (!$this->category->contains($category)) {
         $this->category[] = $category;
         $category->addProjects($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeCategory(Category $category): self
{
    if ($this->category->contains($category)) {
        $this->category->removeElement($category);
        $category->removeProjects($this);
        
    }

    return $this;
}
public function __toString()
{
   return $this->title;
}


}
```

Comment: You say it "will not save". Please add the error message to your question.

Comment: Project::addCategory probably needs the correct signature, the `category` type-hint there should have a capital c.

Comment: @jakumi that didn't work too, i upload a video on youtube hope it can describe more the problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gu5doMiQ_o

Comment: that indeed looks weird. can you add `dump($category)` into your add/removeCategory functions to see if a) it enters the function at all and b) if it enters the if clause? (you have to check in the profiler on the redirect-request

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that the adders and removers are never called. In the case of Category::getProjects you return the collection, which, when changed, will lead to updates in the database, since it's the owning side of the relation.

On the other side however, you got Projects::getCategory, which also returns the collection, which probably is modified, but the changes are not propagated to the database at all, since it's the inverse side.

To fix this, I presume you have to fix your pluralization:

Category's property should be called $projects, the getter should be called `getProjects` and imho `return $this->projects->toArray();` (the implementation details should be hidden), the adder should be named `addProject` (note the missing s) and the remover `removeProject`. Symfony will handle the different pluralizations and understand which methods to call.

the class should be called Project (no plural s) and similarly the getters, adders and removers have their names `getCategories`, `addCategory` and `removeCategory`. again, in the getter return $this->categories->toArray(). providing the collection might lead to the bundle editing the collection directly, especially if the adders and removers are named weirdly.

After these changes (adapting the @ManyToMany annotations too of course), it should work (tm).

Comment: hi again @jakumi i fallow ur steps one by one and again still not working, but in Entities Mapping i got this error https://ibb.co/QFJ2bR3

Answer (score 0):

it worked the mapping was false it should be like this in
category

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Projects::class, mappedBy="categories")
```

and like this in projects

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="projects")
```

then i droped the db and update the schema ... plus the fix of the pluralization
thnx a lot <3 <3

Comment: I actually think, that your (original) mappings were fine as well, but in combination with the broken pluralizations the adder/removers were not called but the collection modified instead. Since you changed which entity is the owning and inverse side, have you double-checked that what worked before (adding projects to categories) still works? - Entity class names really should have no plural s, it's just confusing af.